# memory leak on not freed class_copyPropertyList

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, runtime

So, profiling my app theres some leaks. One is `objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.class, NULL);` not being free'd.

but when I add `free(properties)`

`alloc: *** error for object 0x10b773f58: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

code looks something like this:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {

    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.class, NULL);

    while (*properties != '\0') {

        NSString *pname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(*properties)];
        const char * attrs = property_getAttributes(*properties);

        // do something here and set the value to be encoded

        }
        properties ++;
    }
    free(properties);
}
```

> An array of pointers of type objc_property_t describing the properties declared by the class. Any properties declared by superclasses are not included. The array contains *outCount pointers followed by a NULL terminator. You must free the array with free().

the code works, but leaks. Now when I add `free(properties)` it crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are incrementing the `properties` pointer in the loop, so by the time you call `free(properties)` it is no longer referencing the same memory address. Hence the `pointer being freed was not allocated` message.

You need to either iterate properties in a non-destructive manner, or copy the original pointer value to another pointer variable before the loop.

Something like

```
unsigned int count;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    // ... 
}
free(properties);
```

or

```
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], NULL);
objc_property_t *iterationPointer = properties;
while (*iterationPointer != NULL) {
    // ...
    iterationPointer++;
}
free(properties);
```